# Qt Application parameter -qws

Tags: qt

I'm new to Qt so bit of a novice to the framework.

When launching a Qt executable I pass it the parameter -qws.

Looking at the Qt documentation this sets the application to a QApplication::GuiServer type as per

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#Type-enum

What would I need to pass instead of -qws to set the application type to a QApplication::GuiClient?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do not pass any `-qws` as an argument.

To be sure also check your QApplication constructor.

If

```
QApplication app(argc, argv, QApplication::GuiServer);
```

then change it to

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
```